# How I can to turn off a theme in a especific yii2's view?

Tags: yii2

I am using yii2 with a bootstrap's theme, the theme is great but I need to turn off in one especific view of my controller. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the theme at runtime by overriding the theme mapping. Adjust these for the routes you want to use, so if you are using a different theme, then point the pathMap and baseUrl to that theme, otherwise just point back to the original yii2 view files;

```
$this->getView()->theme = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => '\yii\base\Theme',
    'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/views'],
    'baseUrl' => '@web/views',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change layout use in controller:

```
public $layout = 'YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME';
```

Or in special action:

```
public function actionView(){
   $this->layout = 'YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME';
```

Read for `$layout` property http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$layout-detail

Comment: I do that but the theme don't change. I use yii2-start and I want to turn off the theme of the frontend in a specific view.